# Let $f$ be holomorphic on an open connected subset $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on an open connected subset $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Assume $f\not\equiv 0$ on $\Omega$. If $\mathcal{Z}=\{z\in\Omega:f^{(n)}(z)=0 \hbox{ for all }n=0,1,2,...\}$ then prove that $\mathcal{Z}=\emptyset$ without using identity principle.

Clearly if $\mathcal{Z}\neq\emptyset$, then it implies that $f$ is identically zero. But I'm having trouble showing this in a formal manner.

Comment: you did not define the set phi

Comment: Nevermind, it is the emptyset.

Comment: $\mathcal{Z}$ is clearly closed in $\Omega$ because it is the intersection of all of the closed sets given by $\left(f^{(n)}\right)^{-1}(0)$. That $\mathcal{Z}$ is open follows by considering the radius of convergence of power series expansion of $f$ at each point of $\mathcal{Z}$. Hence it is an open and closed subset of a connected set, and since it isn’t the entire set, it must be the empty set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: By using power series expansions prove that $Z$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$ and use a continuity argument to show $\Omega-Z$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Presumably you only need that $Z$ and $\Omega - Z$ are both open in $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes you do character fill.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose toward a contradiction, that $Z\neq \emptyset$ and let $z_0\in Z$. Then, there is a disk $D(z_0,r)\subset \Omega$ such that $f(z)=\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n$ for all $z\in D$. Thus, $f=0$ in $D$ and so $Z$ is open. On the other hand, if $z\in \overline Z$, then there is a sequence $(z_k)\subseteq Z$ such that $z_k\to z$. As $f^{(n)}$ are continuous, we have $f^{(n)}(z_k)\to f^{(n)}(z)$ so in fact $z\in Z$, which implies that $Z$ is closed. But then, $Z$ and $\Omega\setminus Z$ form  a disconnection of $\Omega$. So $\Omega\setminus Z=\emptyset$ and $f=0$ on $\Omega$, which is a contradiction.